# Manage Topics Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to manage topics in firebase so that I can send only notifications to special topics with additional params.

For example, I have a topic "Users" and I want to send notifications not to all subscribers but only to the logged in ones.

I tried it like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Users")
```

but this sends the message to all users, regardless of whether they are online or offline.

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Users",+CurrentUser).
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Hi Taysir! Your question is a bit broad to answer. However, if your goal is to simply manage the tokens, then I would suggest managing the topics first, then subscribing the users after. There are no *special topics* of that sort. You could implement a custom API if you want to tho. Using `"Users"+CurrentUser)` probably won't work -- I assume you use Firebase Auth on this as well -- since each current user has a unique id.

Comment: @AL. I know that my question is a bit broad .I am looking for the best solution because in my case every user should send always his token to the server by a web service then the server will reply by notification using FCM . And about authentification I don't use Firebase Auth ,I use  an other server work  on it .

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Topics` it will send a notification to all users subscribed to this topic. If you want to send a notification a specific user then you need to retrieve the user registration token, and store it in the database to be able to send a notification later on.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token

To retrieve the current token, call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()`

The registration token changes in the following cases:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

Comment: I think the token changes each time the application is launched ?

Comment: So why I should store Tokens ? Maybe a user can uninstalls/reinstall the app and I have the recent Token in my databse ?

Comment: you store so u will be able to retrieve it in cloud functions for example to be able to send a notification to that token. You need to use the function onNewToken to get the recent token whenever it is updated.

Comment: I used the Token and it works for me .But In my case , I need a special user who has some changes details will be notify ! So haw I can do that ?

Comment: @Taysirboubaker what you are trying to achieve? . in the second line u r passing the whole object , you should send currentuser.id something like that if u wanna create topic for each user

Comment: @Asthme yes this what I am trying to do .But I am asking  For the best solution ,because in this case every user should send always his token to the server  by a web service then the server will reply by notification using FCM

Comment: @Taysirboubaker topics are used for user segmentations. create a segmentation such as age, gender, intrest  and interact with your web service and subscribe topics based on that..

Comment: @Asthme Yes i know .. but in my case I used a topic per user .. I know that is not a better solution but  that is what I can to do now.

Comment: @Taysirboubaker it will work as expected if thats what you want.